# Applying 2 shopping cart rules in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I have products in 6 categories **(say, A,B,C,D,E,F)** and I need to give a discount of $10, if anyone purchase all products of category **A,B,C** And $15 if anyone purchase all products of category **D,E,F**.

I have applied Shopping Cart rules and set conditions if category contains A,B,C (and similarly for D,E,F) give discount.

The rule is not implemented properly, it seems to apply discount twice on **A,B,C**.

Suggestions please

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply the rule only one time set the field "Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To" to 1.

Comment: What I did was I set 2 rules for this and assigned their priorties as 10 and 11. Then for the one with 11 I set stop further rule processing as Yes. Worked for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions, here you can set for which categories goes which discount so let's say item from ABC get certain Discount only and DEF gets certain discount only. Simple as That and You don't need to use Stop Further Rules Processing on this one.